# How to get uniq data from jsonb column from some key which contains array?

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.9 and I have jsonb column in my table product with key SIZE and my goal get all unique available sizes in all products table, how query should look?

Right now I have this, but this is row for each product, I expected like each row equal some unique size gloablly for whole data base, all products

what I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.SIZE FROM (

SELECT
jsonb_build_object('SIZE', p.extras->'SIZE') AS SIZE
FROM products AS p
WHERE p.extras IS NOT NULL
) sub
WHERE sub.SIZE != '{"SIZE": null}';
```

and my result

```
{"SIZE": ["32", "34", "36", "38", "52", "54", "48", "50", "40", "42", "44", "46", "32/34,36/38,52/54,48/50,40/42,44/46"]}
{"SIZE": ["38", "40", "42", "46", "48", "50", "52", "38,40,42,46,48,50,52"]}
{"SIZE": ["270", "150", "270x150cm"]}
{"SIZE": ["30", "33", "30-33"]}
{"SIZE": ["13", "5", "32", "US13.5 / EU32"]}
{"SIZE": ["3", "3 years"]}
{"SIZE": ["25", "5", "40", "25.5 / EU40"]}
{"SIZE": ["6", "23", "US6 / EU23"]}
```

this exapmle contain SIZE 38 in separate row result, regarding that this is dupcate, whould be result with uniq data. I expected result like this

```
["38", "40" .....]
```

or

```
 "38"
 "40"
 ...
```

this is example `extra` column from product row. `extra` column has type jsonb

```
{"SIZE": ["3", "5", "3.5"], "COLOUR": "Vit", "CONDITION": "new", "OWN_COLOUR": "Vit"}
```

SIZE key this is array

**UPDATED**
**RESOLVED**

Thank you everyone, ritgh now two approach for resolver this, with the same result 1154 rows in result, bu in one query present distinct and in another distinct not present, and the same result, but across all products a lot of duplicate sizes, how it's possible, `jsonb_array_elements` generated uniq result by default ?

```
select distinct x.size
from products p
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(p.extras -> 'SIZE') as x(size)

select jsonb_array_elements(p.extras -> 'SIZE') as type
from products AS p
group by type
```

Comment: I don't understand what the output is you want. An array with unique sizes for each product? Or just a list of unique sizes across **all** products?

Comment: exactly - unique sizes across all products. I update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select distinct extras ->> 'SIZE' size
from products
```

You can implement a filtering logic in the `where` clause if needed. Maybe:

```
select distinct extras ->> 'SIZE' size
from products
where extras ->> 'SIZE' is not null
```

On the other hand, if json attribute `SIZE` is an array, then we need to unnest it first:

```
select distinct x.size
from products p
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t.extras -> 'SIZE') as x(size)
```

Comment: no, becuase this query return back data for each orw, but I need globally, what uniq data contains in whole data base

Comment: @shuba.ivan: `select distinct` brings unique values only.

Comment: resut example `["36", "38", "52", "54", "40", "42", "44", "46", "32", "34", "48", "50", "36/38,52/54,40/42,44/46,32/34,48/50"]
["2", "34", "US2 / EU34"]` I don;t need this, "34" duplicated

Comment: @shuba.ivan: ok, so it looks like `SIZE` is an array. See my update.

Comment: `select distinct x.size
from products p
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(p.extras ->> 'SIZE') as x(size)
> ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements_text(text) does not exist
  LINE 3: cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(p.extras ->> 'S...
                             ^
  HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  
> Time: 0.085s`

Comment: @shuba.ivan: sorry, the inner `->>` had to be `->`. Fixed.